# What Replaced Database.ExecuteDataSet

Tags: ado.net

According to Microsoft Website on Database.ExecutedDataSet method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.data.database.executedataset(v=pandp.31).aspx

```
Retired Content 
This content is outdated and is no longer being maintained. It is provided as a 
courtesy for individuals who are still using these technologies. This page may 
contain URLs that were valid when originally published, but now link to sites 
or pages that no longer exist.
```

So my question is what is the latest and greatest perferred method to fill a DataSet or DataTable?

Comment: `.Fill` perhaps? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v5 still has [it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb748692%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx).

Comment: It would be really really helpful if Mircorosft would make it clearer as to what an article relates to. In this case the version the method relates to and link to the NEW content/article/method!

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft wants you to use a DataReader or DataAdapter, here's [Microsoft's page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z.aspx) on filling a DataSet.  It uses the Fill method on a DataAdapter.

You could then use the [Add method](http://asp.dotnetheaven.com/howto/doc/adoplus/UpdateDataFromDB.aspx) to add DataRows to that DataSet.

Comment: I think you are right but do you have any references or article links that make reference to "Microsoft wants you to use a DataReader or DataAdapter"?

Answer (score -1):

"This content is outdated" in this case means that you are looking in old documentation of entlib.

EDIT:
Method is not outdated nor replaced. It still exists in new version of entlib.

EDIT2:
And the method is not deprecated.

Comment: Please don't restate the obvious. Does not answer the question.

Comment: @kevincline Method was not replaced. Method still exists in new version. I just only explained that document is outdated not the method. Question cannot be answered directly because it has wrong thesis.

Comment: Yes, but it's deprecated. The OP asked "what is the new facility that replaces [the deprecated] ExecuteDataSet method?" You said "it's still there, but it's deprecated." The OP already knew that.

Comment: @kevinline It is not deprecated: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440726(v=pandp.60).aspx . And I don't said that it's deprecated. I said that he was looking in old documentation.